# Using a slash in citations

Tags: citations

I am currently reading Dr. Alia Al-Saji's paper on Racialized Time titled "Too Late: Racialized Time and the Closure of the Past".

http://philpapers.org/archive/ALSTLR.pdf

Throughout the text, she seems to cite in a format that I do not recognize. She writes '(pp. 112/90-1)' for example. Could someone please explain this to me?

Many thanks

Comment: The purpose of styles is to provide clarity. I think in this case the guide she's using has failed.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't appear to be a standard method of citation, at least not that I can find. The references section is formatted in APA style, and the in text citations are almost APA except the page numbers. In APA the page number is usually in the reference and not in the citation.
My best guess is that they are indicating (page number/line number) but this does not match any citation standard that I know of.

Comment: It turns out she's citing both an english version, and a french version, of the text.